# Can use WebAssembly from JavaScript in Android WebView?

Tags: android, webview, webassembly

I am using js library for browser application and this library uses wasm. An android application using webview will also be created. Will this library work in webview, as it requires webassembly. That is, does webview support webassembly?

Comment: WebAssembly is supported by all the major browsers, included mobile browsers. I would be surprised if it didn't work. Can you run an experiment and share the answer with us? Should be easy to embed a simple WebAssembly module in an app and deploy it.

Comment: I just checked, and it does support WebAssembly, even Apple's WKWebView supports it since iOS 11.