# Writing Android application through WebAssembly?

Tags: android, webassembly

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals

writes that you can develop Android applications with Java, Kotlin and C++.

Now WebAssembly is taking its way. If I had a compiler for language X that emits WebAssembly code, could I use it for writing Android applications? Would there be some limitations?

Comment: As WebAssembly needs a runtime-environment you would need to run it inside a WebView: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67489278/150978 Alternative approaches are ReactNative which uses it's own Hermes run-time engine with an own byte code (not WebAssembly).